# Why do I get the error "NullReferenceException was unhandled"?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, null, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to make a slider puzzle game and I keep getting the error "NullReferenceException was unhandled" when I call myBoard.paint(e.Graphics) in my form1. Please help me!!!

Here is my code for Form1 (Let me know if I need to post some of my other classes code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SliderPuzzle
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int tileSize;
        private int rowsCols;
        private SlidePuzzle myBoard;
        private Stopwatch timer;
        private int moveCount;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(16, 71);
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
            pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            tileSize = imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
            rowsCols = 3;
            pictureBox1.Width = rowsCols * tileSize;
            pictureBox1.Height = rowsCols * tileSize;
        }

        public void initGame()
        {
            myBoard = new SlidePuzzle(rowsCols, tileSize, imageList1);
            timer = new Stopwatch();
            moveCount = 0;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initGame();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
          this.myBoard.paint(e.Graphics);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myBoard.move(e.Y / tileSize, e.X / tileSize))
                ++moveCount;
            Refresh();
            if (!myBoard.winner())
                return;
            timer.Stop();
            if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You won!!\nIt took you {0} moves and {1:F2} seconds.\nPlay again?", (object)moveCount, (object)timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds), "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                initGame();
                Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update #1: Okay, so I moved myBoard = new SlidePuzzle(rowsCols, tileSize, imageList1); to my constructor, but now none of the images are showing up on it. Here is what It looks like vs what it is supposed to look like: [image]

Edit #2: Okay, I moved it back to where it was before and put

```
if (this.myBoard != null)
        this.myBoard.paint(e.Graphics);
```

instead, and it works a little better and looks better as well. But the images not showing up is still a problem.

Edit #3: Here is the SliderPuzzle.Paint Code:

```
        public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < this.myGrid.getNumRows(); ++r)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.myGrid.getNumCols(); ++c)
                this.myGrid.get(new Location(r, c)).paint(g);
        }
    }
```

Edit #4: Here is the code for the SliderPuzzle Class:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SliderPuzzle
{
    internal class SlidePuzzle
    {
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private int myTileSize;
        private BoundedGrid myGrid;
        private ImageList myImages;
        private Location myBlankLoc;

        static SlidePuzzle()
        {
        }

        public SlidePuzzle(int rowsCols, int tileSize, ImageList images)
        {
            this.myTileSize = tileSize;
            this.myGrid = new BoundedGrid(rowsCols, rowsCols);
            this.myImages = images;
            this.myBlankLoc = new Location(rowsCols - 1, rowsCols - 1);
            this.initBoard();
        }

        private void initBoard()
        {
            int index1 = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < this.myGrid.getNumRows(); ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < this.myGrid.getNumCols(); ++c)
                {
                    this.myGrid.put(new Location(r, c), new Tile(index1, this.myTileSize, new Location(r, c), this.myImages.Images[index1]));
                    ++index1;
                }
            }
            for (int index2 = 0; index2 < 1000; ++index2)
            {
                Location adjacentLocation = this.myBlankLoc.getAdjacentLocation(SlidePuzzle.rand.Next(4) * 90);
                if (this.myGrid.isValid(adjacentLocation))
                {
                    this.swap(this.myBlankLoc, adjacentLocation);
                    this.myBlankLoc = adjacentLocation;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool move(int row, int col)
        {
            Location loc1 = new Location(row, col);
            if (Math.Abs(this.myBlankLoc.getRow() - row) + Math.Abs(this.myBlankLoc.getCol() - col) != 1)
                return false;
            this.swap(loc1, this.myBlankLoc);
            this.myBlankLoc = loc1;
            return true;
        }

        public bool winner()
        {
            int num = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < this.myGrid.getNumRows(); ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < this.myGrid.getNumCols(); ++c)
                {
                    if (this.myGrid.get(new Location(r, c)).getValue() != num)
                        return false;
                    ++num;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void swap(Location loc1, Location loc2)
        {
            Tile tile1 = this.myGrid.put(loc2, this.myGrid.get(loc1));
            Tile tile2 = this.myGrid.put(loc1, tile1);
            tile1.setLocation(loc1);
            tile2.setLocation(loc2);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < this.myGrid.getNumRows(); ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < this.myGrid.getNumCols(); ++c)
                    this.myGrid.get(new Location(r, c)).paint(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update #5: Here is the Tile Class:

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace SliderPuzzle
{
    internal class Tile
    {
        private int myValue;
        private int mySize;
        private Location myLoc;
        private Image myImage;

        public Tile(int value, int tileSize, Location loc, Image img)
        {
            this.myValue = value;
            this.mySize = tileSize;
            this.myLoc = loc;
            this.myImage = img;
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return this.myValue;
        }

        public void setLocation(Location newLoc)
        {
            this.myLoc = newLoc;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(this.myImage, this.myLoc.getCol() * this.mySize, this.myLoc.getRow() * this.mySize);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit #6: Here is the Location Class:

```
namespace SliderPuzzle
{
    internal class Location
    {
        public const int LEFT = -90;
        public const int RIGHT = 90;
        public const int HALF_LEFT = -45;
        public const int HALF_RIGHT = 45;
        public const int FULL_CIRCLE = 360;
        public const int HALF_CIRCLE = 180;
        public const int AHEAD = 0;
        public const int NORTH = 0;
        public const int NORTHEAST = 45;
        public const int EAST = 90;
        public const int SOUTHEAST = 135;
        public const int SOUTH = 180;
        public const int SOUTHWEST = 225;
        public const int WEST = 270;
        public const int NORTHWEST = 315;
        private int row;
        private int col;

        public Location(int r, int c)
        {
            this.row = r;
            this.col = c;
        }

        public int getRow()
        {
            return this.row;
        }

        public int getCol()
        {
            return this.col;
        }

        public Location getAdjacentLocation(int direction)
        {
            int num1 = (direction + 22) % 360;
            if (num1 < 0)
                num1 += 360;
            int num2 = num1 / 45 * 45;
            int num3 = 0;
            int num4 = 0;
            if (num2 == 90)
                num3 = 1;
            else if (num2 == 135)
            {
                num3 = 1;
                num4 = 1;
            }
            else if (num2 == 180)
                num4 = 1;
            else if (num2 == 225)
            {
                num3 = -1;
                num4 = 1;
            }
            else if (num2 == 270)
                num3 = -1;
            else if (num2 == 315)
            {
                num3 = -1;
                num4 = -1;
            }
            else if (num2 == 0)
                num4 = -1;
            else if (num2 == 45)
            {
                num3 = 1;
                num4 = -1;
            }
            return new Location(this.getRow() + num4, this.getCol() + num3);
        }

        public bool equals(Location other)
        {
            if (this.getRow() == other.getRow())
                return this.getCol() == other.getCol();
            else
                return false;
        }

        public int hashCode()
        {
            return this.getRow() * 3737 + this.getCol();
        }

        public int compareTo(Location otherLoc)
        {
            if (this.getRow() < otherLoc.getRow())
                return -1;
            if (this.getRow() > otherLoc.getRow())
                return 1;
            if (this.getCol() < otherLoc.getCol())
                return -1;
            return this.getCol() > otherLoc.getCol() ? 1 : 0;
        }

        public string toString()
        {
            return "(" + (object)this.getRow() + ", " + (string)(object)this.getCol() + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit #7: Here is the last class, the BoundedGrid Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SliderPuzzle
{
    internal class BoundedGrid
    {
        private Tile[,] occupantArray;

        public BoundedGrid(int rows, int cols)
        {
            this.occupantArray = new Tile[rows, cols];
        }

        public int getNumRows()
        {
            return this.occupantArray.GetLength(0);
        }

        public int getNumCols()
        {
            return this.occupantArray.GetLength(1);
        }

        public bool isValid(Location loc)
        {
            if (0 <= loc.getRow() && loc.getRow() < this.getNumRows() && 0 <= loc.getCol())
                return loc.getCol() < this.getNumCols();
            else
                return false;
        }

        public List<Location> getOccupiedLocations()
        {
            List<Location> list = new List<Location>();
            for (int r = 0; r < this.getNumRows(); ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < this.getNumCols(); ++c)
                {
                    Location loc = new Location(r, c);
                    if (this.get(loc) != null)
                        list.Add(loc);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        public Tile get(Location loc)
        {
            if (!this.isValid(loc))
                throw new Exception("Location " + (object)loc + " is not valid");
            else
                return this.occupantArray[loc.getRow(), loc.getCol()];
        }

        public Tile put(Location loc, Tile obj)
        {
            if (!this.isValid(loc))
                throw new Exception("Location " + (object)loc + " is not valid");
            if (obj == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("obj == null");
            Tile tile = this.get(loc);
            this.occupantArray[loc.getRow(), loc.getCol()] = obj;
            return tile;
        }

        public Tile remove(Location loc)
        {
            if (!this.isValid(loc))
                throw new Exception("Location " + (object)loc + " is not valid");
            Tile tile = this.get(loc);
            this.occupantArray[loc.getRow(), loc.getCol()] = (Tile)null;
            return tile;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit #8: When I click on the picturebox, the program crashes and it says the the  timer.Stop(); in form1 gives me a NullReferenceException!!!

Edit #9: Okay, THAT worked... I have found that the images still do not show up, but I think that they are never being placed on the grid. When I click on the grid ( still has no images) It says that I have won. This should only display after I move the tiles into the correct order. Any idea what is going on?

Edit #10: My program finally works now! It turns out I had something missplaced in the constructor of form1, now everything works! The images show up and everything! How cool is that!!!

**THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR YOU CONTRIBUTIONS, I WILL NOW GET A GREAT GRADE ON MY SCHOOL PROJECT!**

Comment: @Silvermind No.. he didn't. (`initGame`, called from `Form_Load`).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes he did, because he is calling `InitializeComponent` before `initGame` which triggers the `Paint`.

Comment: @Silvermind No it doesn't. Try it.

Comment: @Silvermind Hm, doubt it, I just checked and I think that Paint is not executed before Form_Load. At least I'm not getting the same error.

Comment: While you're there.. show us the relevant parts of `InitializeComponent` that relate to the `PictureBox`. I suspect that the paint event isn't actually wired up to the picturebox..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead In that case it wouldn't fire at all right?

Comment: Well I just tried that.. and all appears fine :/

Comment: Just updated my question, now no images are showing up

Comment: Have you putted it at the end of the constructor? And is that code for SlidePuzzle.paint commin' or what?

Comment: Should I post my SliderPuzzle and tile class? Would that be beneficial?

Comment: Added the sliderPizzle.paint method

Comment: It seems like you are somehow setting the myBoard to null. And since it is always null, it is not drawing itself with the current code. Put everything back to beginning and check the call stack when you get that exception. The new code looks good, so it looks like it is deeper.

Comment: In all likelihood, something hasn't been fully initialized when paint is being called. I would suggest putting a breakpoint on the paint code and stepping through to see what the values of your objects are. This will help you identify exactly what's wrong and give us more information to help you find the cause.

Comment: Posted the SliderPuzzle and Tile Classes

Comment: Ok, if I'm not wrong, you have 8 images in total but you are drawing 9 of them, when you try to draw the last one in fails. Can you check that?

Comment: Can you tell me where I am actually trying to draw 9 of them, I don't see it.

Comment: There's a 3x3 grid you're creating.. `new BoundedGrid(rowsCols, rowsCols); // 3x3`. You're looping over that everywhere.

Comment: Yes but it would fail in the initBoard() if he doesn't have enough images. This is very strange.

Comment: Heck, I should have 9 images... 8 numbers and one blank...

Comment: @DrewStauft My advice is to step through your code.. line by line.. to find the issue. It is becoming hard to help with such a large amount of code. Debug debug debug!

Comment: Should I post the remaining two classes Nikola?

Comment: Okay, so, I am not even sure witch class to narrow it down to. It just doesnt make sense to me! I mean, I am pretty sure it is not a problem with Form1 because that has nothing to directly do with the tiles...

Comment: I only have one problem so far, the images just won't paint!

Comment: Should I take down some of the code that seems irrelivent? Like the form1, the location, and the BoundedGrid?

Comment: Strange, the code looks good, the only thing that has left is to check in debugger. Is it happening after you click with the mouse (make a move)?

Comment: It happens right when I start up the application

Comment: When I click on the picturebox, the program crashes and it says the the  timer.Stop(); in form1 gives me a NullReferenceException!!!

Comment: Ok, than your Form_Load event is not wired to the Form

Comment: There is NOTHING at all in the Form1_Load_1

Comment: How do I make sure that the images are actually loading, I know they are not displaying, but...

Comment: No, you don't get it, because there is nothing there, your actual Form1_Load event never gets called (the one where you are initializing your board), add this code at the end of the Form1 constructor `this.Load +=Form1_Load;`

Comment: This is because you somehow added other Form1_Load_1 that gets called instead of the Form1_Load

Comment: Okay, THAT worked... I have found that the images still do not show up, but I think that they are never being placed on the grid. When I click on the grid ( still has no images) It says that I have won. This should only display after I move the tiles into the correct order. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: OK, I'll put the last thing as answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those problems that will give you headaches.  Trying to nail down the exact sequence of events is fine, when you can guarantee that the events are never going to be invoked out of sequence.  Unfortunately the `Paint` event is one that gets fired at all sorts of odd times, any may be fired even before the `Load` event.

The only real answer is to ***never*** rely on events being fired in a particular sequence.  Always check that your `myBoard` object is valid before trying to paint it:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.myBoard != null)
        this.myBoard.paint(e.Graphics);
}
```

And yes, as others have noted, it is better to create all of your objects as soon as possible - in the constructor for instance, which is what a constructor is *for* after all.  Even then, you can still get events being fired by actions in the constructor that will ruin your whole day.  Your even handlers should be set as late as possible in the constructor code to account for this.

Rule(s) of thumb:

- if you're creating custom objects that will be used in event handlers, always try to create and initialize them prior to calling `InitializeComponent` in the constructor.
- Wire up your event handlers as late as possible, especially for things like `Paint` - it won't be useful before your constructor is done, so do it last in the constructor.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it gives a practical workaround.. however, `Paint` isn't called _before_ `Load`.. it is called after events like `Layout`, `Activated` and `VisibleChanged`. Which makes sense.. how can a child control throw a `Paint` event when the parent form hasn't even rendered its contents?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Because `Paint` is not ***only*** invoked by standard event flow, it is called at all sorts of random times by various code that we have no control over.  It's a major pain in the ass, but `Paint` is the worst offender here.  And yes, it **does** get invoked before `Load` in some cases.

Comment: Can you link me to sources where it says that Corey? I am unable to find any (and will happily eat my words if that is the case!). Keeping in mind that the `Paint` event is wired up to a _child_ control.. not the `Paint` event of the form itself..

Answer (score 2):

Your actual `Form1_Load` event never gets called (the one where you are initializing your board).
Add this code at the end of the Form1 constructor `this.Load +=Form1_Load;`

Comment: Okay, THAT worked... I have found that the images still do not show up, but I think that they are never being placed on the grid. When I click on the grid ( still has no images) It says that I have won. This should only display after I move the tiles into the correct order. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @DrewStauft Regarding images, are you sure they are all added to the ImageList? Also, maybe you set all of them to the blank one when you shuffle them. Check your app's logic.

Comment: @DrewStauft That is an entirely different problem. If you cannot figure it out yourself, do feel free to come back to SO, posting this specific problem (along with the related code) as a new question.

Comment: It turns out it DID have something to do with this problem, Jan. I had missplaced the definition of the myGrid object in the constructor of the Form1. I moved it back and everything was golden!

Comment: I'm glad we got this one sorted :)

Comment: I get the distinct impression that everything I type in this question just humiliates myself further...

Answer (score -1):

Your `pictureBox1.Paint` event is raised before your `Form1.Load` event. Move

```
myBoard = new SlidePuzzle(rowsCols, tileSize, imageList1);
```

to your constructor and you should be fine.

Comment: Have you tried this? Because it works.. without doing that (`Load` is called before it's controls raise `Paint` events).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead In the `Paint` handler, he gets a `NullReferenceException`, but after having moved the `myBoard` initialization to the constructor instead of the `Load` handler, he doesn't anymore (see update). Yet you claim that his `Paint` handler was NOT called before the `Load` handler? That does not make any sense.

Comment: No `NullRef`.. but nothing else either. I suspect there is a lot more to this than we're being shown.

Comment: Would you like me to post my SliderPuzzle and Tile classes?

Comment: @DrewStauft Yes, please. Any little bit helps.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Look at Edit #2. An explicit null check makes everything better. Do you still want to maintain that `Paint` cannot *possibly* be called before `Load`?

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus It makes everything better because myBoard.Paint never gets called, because myBoard is null all the time, and clearly, the code initializes it. Therefore something is setting myBoard to null. I think we can't see the whole code

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Clearly something else is going on. No matter what I do.. I cannot reproduce this. The order of events is as I am saying.. so that is why I am sticking to it. If someone can point me to a source that says otherwise I will happily be proved wrong! (and I will also go read up on WinForms event's again that's for sure!). I just don't understand how a _child control_ can raise a `Paint` event **before** it's parent has.

Comment: Posted the SliderPuzzle and Tile Classes

Comment: Do you want me to post the remaining two classes? Cuz I can if you all want me to.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead AFAIK, any WM_PAINT system message triggers a `Paint` event. A WM_PAINT system message is sent whenever windows thinks "Well now, this would be a perfect time, wouldn't it".

Comment: @DrewStauft If you can, sure. Somehow, I doubt that the problem is within those, however. The real "problem solver" is actually not to ever rely on events being executed in the proper order. They might be. And in many cases, they might not be.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus `WM_PAINT` is only raised when the applications window needs to be drawn.. put a breakpoint in a simple C++ Win32 app, or a C# WInforms app on `WM_NCCREATE` or `Form_Load` respectively.. is there a visible window when the breakpoint is hit? ....

Comment: Also, `WM_PAINT` is a queued message.. the other relevant messages related to creating a window are not queued. They are forcefully pushed directly into the window proc at time of creation (all of the activation/load/window creation window messages do this). `WM_PAINT` is then queued after this (along with other "drawing"/setup related messages).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I won't verify your claims at this time. However, my answer explains the experienced behaviour, while you have as of yet failed to provide a reasonable answer to why said behaviour occurs. As you said also, I am prepared to eat my words. If something else turns out to be the miscreant here, I certainly will. Until then, the events-out-of-order thing is my explanation, and I am sticking with it, no matter the downvote! :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Edit #8 would apparently make me eat my words. As it appears to turn out, the `Load` event handler was/is not properly registered. So... yeah. Just tell me how you would like me to eat my words. I was thinking... mayonnaise?

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus I was with Simon all along, there is no way OnPaint could be called before OnLoad. You can try that yourself. And don't eat your words, this discussions are great, they make us all better in what we are doing

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic I cannot on all possible platforms. But, yeah, you guys were right, and I was wrong. I am man enough to admit that, and not just quietly delete my answer ;)

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus No worries at all! :)

Comment: It turns out this actually turned out to be my downfall. I had missplaced the definition of the myGrid object in the constructor of the Form1 (Which I was told to do). When I moved it back to the initGame method, everything showed up!

Comment: @DrewStauft Apologies. I was starting from the wrong point, as it turns out.